# Having conditional statements on BUILD_TYPE variable a good design?

Tags: cmake

So, I have build scripts that have conditions on the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE. I am curious to understand if it is a good design.

It would be great if someone can suggest a course or a good book on cmake design.

example:
[image]

Comment: Note that not all generators are single configuration generators. E.g. the Visual Studio generates a solution containing all configurations for a single architecture. For these multi configuration generators checking `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` fails. In many cases generator expressions can be used to set properties dependent on the configuration and allow this to work both in single and mutliple configuration generators,but this doesn't seem to be an option here.That being said are you sure you actually want a seperate configuraton for this and not simply add a target excluded from the default build?

Comment: Hi, Fabian. I definitely what my design to work with all the build systems CMake supports. The problem I've is... Based on the build type not only my compiler options change but my source files and compiler will also change. I'm new to Cmake I wasn't sure how to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

No, this ties your project to single-configuration generators. It is not safe to test `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in an if statement in general.

On Visual Studio, XCode, and Ninja Multi-Config, the variable will be empty and your build will fail unnecessarily.

Your question doesn't have enough detail for me to suggest an alternative to what you're doing.

> It would be great if someone can suggest a course or a good book on cmake design

[Professional CMake: A Practical Guide by Craig Scott](https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/) is the best book on CMake I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I'm starting a project for which I want four configurations for now. Those will be debug, release, analysis, and unit-test. The reason for having the Analysis and unit-test is because the source files for these builds will be different. I wasn't sure how else could I achive this in Cmake.

Comment: You can include source files conditionally based on the build type using a generator expression, eg. `$<$<CONFIG:Analysis>:my_analysis_only_source.cpp>`